# Тональности в качестве прилагательных - слитно, раздельно или через дефис?

Tags: правописание

Названия тональностей обычно пишутся раздельно. Например,

> Симфония до минор Брамса

А как писать, если тональность выступает в роли прилагательного?

> Фамажорная гамма, фа-мажорная гамма, фа мажорная гамма?
>
> доминорная симфония Брамса, до-минорная симфония Брамса, до минорная симфония Брамса?

Я понимаю, что звучит несколько нелитературно, но все же эти фразы употребляются, несмотря на очевидный вариант перефразировки:

> гамма фа мажор, симфония Брамса до минор.

Меня интересует, согласно каким рассуждениям/правилам нужно предпочесть одно из написаний.

Comment: через дефис) тут ни рассуждений, ни правил, просто так сложилось. Ну и традиции нет словообразования композитных прилагательных без дефиса хотя бы.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> до-диез мажор
>   до-диез-мажорный

Русский орфографический словарь Российской академии наук.
Отв. ред. В. В. Лопатин.
© Электронная версия, «ГРАМОТА.РУ», 2001–2007.

Comment: Национальный корпус русского языка тоже [показывает](http://search.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=fol1&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F4%E0-%EC%E0%E6%EE%F0%ED%E0%FF+), что через дефис.